# Understanding the Taylor expansion of a function

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Suppose

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$$

We know this function is defined everywhere and is continuous everywhere and so on...

Using the geometric series, we can write

$$ \frac{1}{1+x^2} = \sum (-x^2)^n = \sum (-1)^n x^{2n} $$

But, this only converges iff $|-x^2|<1$ iff $|x|<1$. Why does this converge only in $(-1,1)$ when we know it is defined everywhere, though?

Comment: You can also create other series representations that will work on different intervals: $\sum_n f^{(n)}(a)/n!(x-a)^n$. That will possibly converge on some interval centered at $a$.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nx^{2n}$ is the power series representation on $(-1,1)$ of the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$.

The series does not represent the function $f$ for $|x|\ge 1$.

We can find a series representation of $f(x)$ that is valid for $|x|>1$.  To do so, we write

$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{1+x^2}&=\frac1{x^2}\frac{1}{1+1/x^2}\\\\
&=\frac1{x^2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nx^{-2n}\\\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n x^{-2(n+1)}
\end{align}$$

which converges for all $|x|>1$ and diverges elsewhere.

Note that the latter series is given in terms of reciprocal powers of $x^2$.  If $x$ is extended to be complex, this is the Laurent series for $|x|>1$.

Answer (score 40):

This is a great question.  It shows in a nutshell why analysis should be done in the complex plane, not on the real line.

The function $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{1+x^2}$ is defined everywhere on the real line, as you pointed out — but it is not defined everywhere on the complex plane.  In particular, it's not defined at $x=i$ or $-i,$ because the denominator becomes $0$ for those values of $x.$

The Maclaurin series for this function, $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n x^{2n},$ has a circle of convergence in the complex plane, centered at the origin.  This circle cannot have radius greater than $1,$ since the series doesn't converge at $i$ and $-i,$ which are at a distance of $1$ from the origin.

In fact, the circle of convergence for this power series is the unit circle.  That means that it will converge everywhere inside the unit circle, and it will diverge everywhere outside the unit circle.  (As for points on the circumference of the circle, you would need to look more closely to see for which of those it converges and for which it diverges.)

For completeness, I should add that not every Maclaurin series has a circle of convergence: some converge everywhere, and some converge only at the origin.  But between these two extremes, there will be a circle centered at the origin such that the series converges inside the circle and diverges outside the circle (with the points on the circumference requiring further investigation).

Comment: In particular, Hadamard (i believe) showed that if $f$ is analytic on a domain in $\Bbb C$, and is maximally extended (that is, there is no analytic function $g$ defined on a larger domain that is equal to $f$ on its domain), then the Taylor series of $f$ at some point $a$ will have a radius of convergence equal to the distance from $a$ to the nearest point not in the domain of $f$.

Comment: It is clear what the last paragraph means, but is there any theorem about power series that would fail if radii $0$ or $\infty$ were included?

Comment: One thing that's always confused me is why we look at *radii* of convergence. Why radius (implying a circle)? Why not a rectangle, or a star, or some other shape? Would you mind addressing this if possible? I ask because merely saying that the radius on the imaginary axis is 1 doesn't really say anything about the radius on the real axis to someone who doesn't already know the answer...

Comment: A function that only converges at the origin certainly has a circle of convergence; that circle has radius $0$.

Comment: @zyx asked: "...is there any theorem about power series that would fail if radii $0$ or $\infty$ were included?"  Of course in some sense these are just circles of radius $0$ or $\infty,$ so there isn't really a difference. On the other hand, if the radius of convergence is $0,$ then there's no region on which the series converges, and if the radius is $\infty,$ the power series represents an entire function, and all the theorems about entire functions apply to it.

Comment: @Mehrdad This isn't an arbitrary convention. There's a theorem: If a power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$ converges at a point $z_0,$ then it converges for all $z$ of magnitude $\lt|z_0|.$ If it diverges at a point $z_0,$ then it diverges for all $z$ of magnitude $\gt|z_0|.$ It follows that there's a circle $C$ centered at $(0,0)$ such that the sum converges in the interior of $C,$ and diverges in the exterior of $C$ (no claim is made about convergence/divergence for points on the circumference), with the caveat that it's possible for $C$ to be a "circle" of radius $0$ or radius $\infty.$

Comment: @Mehrdad Other series, of different forms, may have differently-shaped regions on which they converge: a circle centered at a point other than the origin, the exterior of a circle, a half-plane, etc. For example, for a half-plane, check out a series of the form $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n e^{nz}$ (which can be viewed as a power series in $e^z).$

Comment: @celtschk "A function that only converges at the origin certainly has a circle of convergence; that circle has radius $0.\!"$ Sure, but if I hadn't spelled out that special case, somebody would have posted to say I was wrong, that that's not a circle!  (And they would have been right.)  The situation is similar for the case where the radius of convergence is infinite.

Comment: @MitchellSpector: You should mention this in the answer! :) What theorem is this?

Comment: @Mehrdad I think it's called the Cauchy-Hadamard theorem. This was mentioned in Paul Sinclair's comment. It's a staple in any complex analysis book.  (As I recall, Ahlfors' text does it well, but it's been many years since I've looked at that book, and the theorem is covered in many other books too.)

Comment: @MitchellSpector: Thanks!! I haven't taken complex analysis so I guess that's why I didn't know it :) it just always bugged me ever since I started doing series in high school since it came with zero explanation.

Comment: @Mehrdad If you enjoy this type of material, I highly recommend reading some complex analysis, or taking a course in it. It may be the most beautifully coherent theory in all of mathematics (and I say this as someone who specialized in mathematical logic, not analysis).

Comment: @MitchellSpector: Of course the circle with radius $0$ is a circle. That's unlike the case of radius infinity, where there's indeed no circle, as there are no points at infinite distance of a given point.

Comment: @celtschk Yes, you could argue that the "circle" with radius $0$ is a circle, and in some cases (like the one here) that would make sense, although if someone wanted to count it as a circle in a mathematical paper, they would specify that for clarity (it's an edge case that people might or might not consider a circle in practice).  But it differs in some important ways from a circle of radius $\gt 0;$ for example, its interior isn't a region (a region is defined as a *non-empty* connected open set).  [And if I had called it a circle in my answer, someone would still have objected to that too.]

Comment: That shifts the question to whether there is any situation where non-emptiness of the interior of the circle is important.  The empty set is open and connected, and the circle of radius R=0 does contain all circles of smaller radius (which are empty) in its interior.

Comment: @celtschk It's just a minor question of nomenclature, of the sort that would, for clarity's sake, be spelled out one way or the other in any paper that relied on whether the term "circle" should be taken to include circles of radius $0$ or not. (The interior being empty isn't a trivial difference though; you can't usefully integrate around the circumference, for instance. In general, if you admit these $0$-radius circles, you're  going to have to be very careful that everything you claim for circles is really true for them too. )

Answer (score 6):

A more graphical interpretation for this case. Not a proof, more insights.

Mostly because $f$ is a function that tend to $0$ at $\pm \infty$. This is not a natural behavior for polynomials, and even less so when they have higher degrees.

However, the function is very smooth far away from $\pm \infty$, that is, around $0$. Here, higher degree polynomials fit the function much better, even more at higher degrees. This is illustrated in the following pîcture, the top one showing that the behavior is very different between $0$ neighborhoods or $+ \infty$, the bottom one only at the vicinity of $0$.

[image: Taylor approximations]

The quality of the approximation, and the radius of convergence, is highly related to the behavior of the coeficients $a_n$ multiplying the terms  $x^n$. Here, the  reason why the border is at $x=1$ is due to the fact you have $|a_n|=1$, which leads to a divergence of the series at $x=\pm 1$. Would the coefficients decrease at a different speed  (for instance $|a_n|\sim \frac{1}{r^n}$), this would modify the radius of convergence to $r$.

Comment: This argument is not completely convincing. For example, the Maclaurin series for $g(x)=e^{-x^2}$ has infinite radius of convergence, and still $g(x) \to 0$ as $x \to \pm\infty$...

Comment: @HansLundmark My answer needs caveat, true